# Filter search by date (dd/mm/yyyy) working, but crushing other queries

Tags: mysql, symfony

I had a hard time understanding how to filter things by date in my project this way `dd/mm/yyyy`

After some hair pulling I finally succeeded with the code I will share to you to make work my filter bar by searching by date.

However, all other research (by name as an example) doesn't show anything anymore.

Its when I change this line

```
$fullDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "d/m/Y", $filter);
```

to this line

```
$fullDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "d/m/Y", date("d/m/Y");
```

that my research by date works but not the other search (names, brand).
on the contrary, all other research work (by name, by brand), but not the date anymore.

so I really don't know what I messed up and i'm starting to become a little dry brained.

here is my query

```
public function getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, User $user, $archive, $filter)
    {

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("opn");

        $fullDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "d/m/Y", date("d/m/Y"));

        $or = new Orx();

        if($fullDate !== false) {
            $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.dateCreation', ':filter'));
        } else {
            $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.id', ':filter'));
            $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.vehiculeMarque', ':filter'));
            $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.clientNom', ':filter'));
            $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.clientPrenom', ':filter'));
        }

        $or->addMultiple($textFilters);
        $qb->andWhere($or);

        $query = $qb
            ->andWhere("opn.type = :type")
            ->andWhere("opn.resellerId = :reseller")
            ->andWhere("opn.archive = :archive")
            ->setParameters([
                "type" => $type,
                "reseller" => $user->getId(),
                'archive' => $archive,
                'filter' => '%' . $filter . '%'
            ])
            ->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")
            ->getQuery()
        ;

        return $query;
    }
```

and my filter bar in my twig

```
<form action="{{ path('st_backoffice_commerce_offre') }}" method="get">
         <input name="filter" type="text" value="{{ app.request.query.get('filter') }}">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{ 'commerce.resultsoperation.display.filter'|trans }}</button>
         <a href="{{ path('st_backoffice_commerce_offre') }}" class="btn btn_default">{{ 'commerce.resultsoperation.display.refresh'|trans }}</a>
  </form>
```

Comment: I have no Symfony experience, but one solution which might kill two birds with one stone would be to store your dates in an ISO format, e.g. `yyyy/mm/dd`.  Then you wouldn't need any massaging on the PHP or MySQL sides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but doesn't do the trick, i'm still blocked to research other things than date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I succeeded at making that work in a really weird way. I do not know why it is working, but the code i'm going to show you, work for all research, including date, name etc....

here is the answer: i removed the `if` condition. So here is the code.

```
public function getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, User $user, $archive, $filter)
    {

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("opn");

        $fullDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "d/m/Y", date("d/m/Y"));

        $or = new Orx();

        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.dateCreation', ':filter'));
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.id', ':filter'));
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.vehiculeMarque', ':filter'));
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.clientNom', ':filter'));
        $textFilters[] = $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->like('opn.clientPrenom', ':filter'));


        $or->addMultiple($textFilters);
        $qb->andWhere($or);

        $query = $qb
            ->andWhere("opn.type = :type")
            ->andWhere("opn.resellerId = :reseller")
            ->andWhere("opn.archive = :archive")
            ->setParameters([
                "type" => $type,
                "reseller" => $user->getId(),
                'archive' => $archive,
                'filter' => '%' . $filter . '%'
            ])
            ->orderBy("opn.dateCreation", "DESC")
            ->getQuery()
        ;

        return $query;
    }
```

So this actually works